# Can I use DPDK as a packet capture module for a network monitoring application?

Tags: libpcap, packet-capture, dpdk, pf-ring

My passive `network monitoring` application needs packets to be captured from network interface (at higher packet rates). The packet capture module should be able to call a monitoring function upon capture of each packet (and also write the packet in to `pcap` file).

I thought of using `DPDK` as the packet capture module in my monitoring application (as we use `pcap_loop` and `pfring_loop` in `libpcap` and `pfring` respectively), but I am not sure whether this is one of the use cases of `DPDK`, or, is `DPDK` meant to be used like this?.

So my questions are..
Can I use `DPDK` to fulfill my requirements?,  If yes how to start?.

OS: Linux.
Karnal version: 4.
DPDK version: Latest stable.
Capture on physical device.
The capturing application has root privileges and will be used by the network administrator (as part of passive asset discovery).
I want to use DPDK because it supports capture at line rate upto 10 Gbps

Thank you.

Comment: can you please update with the following information OS, kernel version, DPDK version, physical or vdev, diagram or layout on capture plan and who owns monitoring application? does monitoring application own the NIC or vdev? packet rate for capture.

Comment: Thanks for updating the details, and mentioning you are using Physical NIC and not vdev. So if you are requirement is capture packets in PCAP format for physical NIC, did you try using DPDK PDUMP. https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/howto/packet_capture_framework.html.

Comment: @VipinVarghese, Thanks a lot, For me the information on DPDK is overwhelming, and I read about DPDK PDUMP and found that I can only dump the packets into pacp file. But I want to capture all the packets on the interface (in promiscuous mode) and do some processing on each packet as it received (for example calling a C function on each packet received as I already did using pf-ring)

Comment: dpdk pdump can write to file or put to iface as raw packets. But as your update in comment, it looks like you need to update or modify the packet contents. If this is true, you do not need pdump you just need an application to process rx packets. do you want to sync on this on skype

Comment: based on the your comment update, looks like you are simply trying to replace the current logic `pf-ring` with DPDK API. It is doable, but what is the error or issue you are facing? can you please update.

Comment: Thank you Vipin, You are right, I want to replace the `pf-ring` API in an application written in C language with `DPDK`. But I wasn't sure it is doable so I have not tried. I want to know how to do it. And the application meant to capture all network packets on a `SPAN` port and extract network inventory details from them, hence I need to parse each and every packet to extract the data.

Comment: I have updated and answered your question, please check. if this helps you accept and upvote

Comment: if you find the answer useful please accept and upvote to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updates and clarification in comment the request is `Can one replace an existing application which PF_RING API calls with DPDK API which is written in C?`. Simple answer to it is **yes it can be done**.

Here is how one should start

1. identify the Platform (preferably Linux/BSD, windows 21.02 is still work in progress)
2. identify the processor [list of supported CPU](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/)
3. Identify a NIC to use from [LIST of DPDK NIC](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/)
4. Set up the Linux environment with [Linux Enviroment](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/index.html)
5. Explore basic example/skeleton for [basicfwd usage](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/skeleton.html)
6. get the start of ethernet header for packet using DPDK API `rte_pktmbuf_mtod`. There are many samples in DPDK/examples folder which does the same.
7. Invoke the packet processing function logic between rx_burst and tx_burst of example/skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of libpcap can themselves use DPDK, at least on Linux.  The libpcap on your system might, or might not, be configured to use it.  (There are also versions of libpcap modified to use PF_RING.)